# Google Cloud Healthcare API not supporting PlanDefintion/$apply and Activity Definition/$apply

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, google-healthcare-api

I am trying to create a carePlan as output by doing $apply operation on PlanDefinition and ActivityDefintion.

For example:

https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<project_id>/locations/<location_name>/datasets/<dataset_name>/fhirStores/<fhirstore_name>/fhir/PlanDefinition/<plandefintion_id>/$apply?subject=Patient/

This endpoint is throwing Error 404 (Not Found)!!1.

Tried many ways of making this endpoint work as per FHIR R4 documentation. But seems like GCP is not yet supporting $apply operation in PlanDefintion and ActivityDefinition in both v1 and v1beta1 version of Healthcare APIs.

Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

On their [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/fhir) they indicate that you can view your server's capabilities by retrieving the CapabilityStatement. If this does not list the $apply operation, it is not supported.

And actually further down on the page, the documentation mentions: "Most extended operations aren't implemented". If you need that functionality, maybe you can reach out to them to see if it can be integrated, or look into using a different FHIR server implementation.